# Python return list from function

Tags: python, list, function

I have a function that parses a file into a list. I'm trying to return that list so I can use it in other functions.

```
def splitNet():
    network = []
    for line in open("/home/tom/Dropbox/CN/Python/CW2/network.txt","r").readlines():
        line = line.replace("\r\n", "")
        line = string.split(line, ',')
        line = map(int, line)
        network.append(line)
    return network
```

When I try to print the list outside of the function (for debugging) I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'network' is not defined
```

Is there something simple I am doing wrong or is there a better way to pass variables between functions without using globals?

Comment: Can you add the code where you assign network back to a variable in scope and print it?

Comment: your splitNet() function looks alright. Could you post the code tht prints the netwark-list?

Comment: If you want to pass variables between functions: why not using parameters? Why avoid globals? You can also put your function as methods and save the result inside the class instance no ?

Comment: I'm guessing you've found the problem judging from what you said because I don't do anything like that. At the moment I am just calling the function so it runs and then calling `print network`

Comment: Hi, i see you reverted my edit. I would argue, you should provide code that illustrates the problem and can be reproducible. Right now it is not complete. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Variables cannot be accessed outside the scope of a function they were defined in.

Simply do this:

```
network = splitNet()
print network
```

Comment: Thanks. Man do I feel dumb now haha.

Comment: @Schmooo don't worry, I did this a while back :)

Comment: Won't the list 'network' (created inside the function) be destroyed once the function execution ends ? Won't it be erased from the memory ? If it's erased, how can we access outside the function.

Answer (score 18):

I assume you are not assigning the returned value to a variable in scope.

ie. you can't do

```
splitNet()
print network
```

instead you would

```
network = splitNet()
print network
```

or for that matter

```
my_returned_network_in_scope = splitNet()
print my_returned_network_in_scope
```

otherwise you could declare network outside of the splitNet function, and make it global, but that is not the recommended approach.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the edit, yes a typo.  Going back and forth from Java to Python to PHP to Go to Erlang to C++... messes me up something awful.

Comment: Know what you mean... I've just started with Python and I've started dropping them in my PHP/Objective-C now!

Answer (score 8):

The names of variables in a function are not visible outside, so you need to call your function like this:

```
networks = splitNet()
print(networks)
```

A couple of other notes:

- You may want to convert your function to an iterator, using [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained).
- You don't need to call `readlines`; the function itself is an iterator.
- Your function may be leaking the file handle. Use the `with` statement.
- You can use `str.split`, which is more readable and easier to understand than `string.split`.
- Your file looks to be a CSV file. Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

In summary, this is how your code should look like:

```
import csv
def splitNet():
    with open("/home/tom/Dropbox/CN/Python/CW2/network.txt") as nf:
        for line in csv.reader(nf, delimiter=','):
            yield map(int, line)
network = list(splitNet())
print (network)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function is returning a list so you have to assign it to a variable and than try to print it.

```
network = splitNet()
print network
```

For example

```
>>> def mylist():
...    myl = []
...    myl.append('1')
...    return myl
...
>>> my_list = mylist()
>>> my_list
['1']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually called the function yet? This works fine (in the Python interpreter)

```
 >>> def f():
 ...   network = []
 ...   network.append(1)
 ...   network.append(2)
 ...   network.append(3)
 ...   return network
 ...
 >>> network = f()
 >>> print network
 [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may declare the name of the variable assigned to the list as `global`, like this:

```
def get_list():
    global destination_list
    destination_list = []
    destination_list.extend(('1','2','3'))
    return destination_list

get_list()
print(destination_list)
```

Comment: True, but not the best way. Since the value is returned, it should be assigned rather than put in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
L=[1, 2, 3]

def rl(l): 
    return l

[*ll] = rl(L) # ll is in a list

ll
# >>> [1, 2, 3]

*t, = rl(L)   # ll is in a tuple

t
# >>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an item or list from a definition, you could define it before hand and use it as a variable during the initial writing of said definition. Unless it has to be defined within the definition. In this case you won't need to write in a return command at the end.

```
network = []

def splitNet(network):
    for line in open("/home/tom/Dropbox/CN/Python/CW2/network.txt","r").readlines():
        line = line.replace("\r\n", "")
        line = string.split(line, ',')
        line = map(int, line)
        network.append(line)

print network # Will print the list you've appended. But it is now a usable object.
```