# Python function directly altering list, not returning it

Tags: python, function

**[SOLVED]**

So the code goes like:

```
>>> a = [1,3,2]
>>> my_func(a)
>>> a == []
True
```

Where my_func alters the list without returning it. I know how to do this in C with pointers, but really confused over a python solution.

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:** So I am doing a radix sort which has a helper function and the helper function returns the sorted list. I want the main function to alter the original list instead of returning it:

```
def radix(a):
    base = ...
    temp = radix_helper(a, index, base)
    a[:] = []
    a.extend(temp)
```

So it would run as:

```
>>> a = [1,3,4,2]
>>> radix(a)
>>> a
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Are you asking why this is allowed to happen, or do you want to know how to write a function that does this?  It's not clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9317025

Answer (score 2):

Lists are mutable, so all you need to do is mutate the list within the function.

```
def my_func(l):
  del l[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python passes parameters by value, but the value of `a` is a reference to a list object. You can modify that list object in your function:

```
def my_func(a):
    a.append('foobar')
```

This can be the cause of unplanned side effects if you forget that you're working directly with the object in question.

Comment: No, if you do `a = []` inside your function, `a` now refers to a *different* object than what was passed to the function.  This will not give the effect the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

If the identifier is fixed then you can use the `global` keyword:

```
a = [1,2,3]

def my_func():
    global a
    a = []
```

Otherwise you can modify the argument directly:

```
a = [1,2,3]

def my_func(a):
    a.clear()
```