# Printing lists with special characters

Tags: python, list

I have a list with special characters like `l1 = ['øk', 'løk', 'pølse', 'pål', 'æl']`
How can I print or return this list in a function so the special characters are included. I know you can write `print u'Ølske'`

but what do you do when you have lists?`

When I run this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
l1 = [u"ål", u"øk", u"møk"]

print l1
```

I get:

```
[u'\xe5l', u'\xf8k', u'm\xf8k']
```

Comment: Where do you want to print them?

Comment: What have you tried? When I tried that, "ascii ordinal not in range" exception appeared. in the list try putting u'' for each element, as in the print command. remember u'' denotes a unicode string, it's not a special print command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947173/printing-unicode-char-inside-a-list

Comment: With python 3, you will not have to play with encoding traps...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317025/python-return-list-from-function

Comment: it works fine in for example `print l1[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the small hack that will do the job:

```
>>> l1 = [u"ål", u"øk", u"møk"]
>>> print '[' + ', '.join("'" + x + "'" for x in l1) + ']'
>>> ['ål', 'øk', 'møk']
```

Python 3.0 should print the special characters as is from the list without any hassles.