# Python function to return listed imports gives empty result, but works line by line

Tags: python, global, python-3.4, python-module

Adapting code from

[How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules)

to look like

```
def imports():
    import types

    Module = None
    Modules = list()

    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            Module = val.__name__
            Modules.append(Module)

    return Modules
```

and saved as imports.py. Intended to be activated in the form

```
Modules = imports.imports()
```

Instead, returns an empty list `Modules`.

Have looked here

[Python.org classes + generators](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#generators)

here

[Python.org Data structures: list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

and here

[Python return list from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317025/python-return-list-from-function)

and not getting it.

When I run the function body line by line I get the desired result (a list of the imported modules stored in `Modules`). When it's run as a defined function it gives an empty list. Why is my returned list variable empty? I've also tried `yield` with the same result.

Comment: You could write that as a list comprehension: `return [module.__name__ for module in globals().values() if isinstance(module, types.ModuleType)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`globals()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) returns the global namespace for the *module it is used in*. You are seeing the modules that are imported in your `imports` module, and there are 0 such imports. You can't use this function if you wanted to access the globals of the code that called your function.

You'd have to use the globals of the *calling frame* instead; in CPython you can do this with the [`sys._getframe()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe), which returns a frame object; the `f_globals` attribute on that frame is the global namespace of the caller of your function:

```
caller_frame = sys._getframe(1)
for name, val in caller_frame.f_globals.items():
```

Alternatively, have the caller pass in a namespace; that way you can list the modules used in *any* module:

```
def imports(namespace=None):
    import types, sys

    if namespace is None:
        # default: caller globals
        namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals

    modules = []

    for name, val in namespace.items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            module_name = val.__name__
            modules.append(module_name)

    return modules
```

The above version still uses `sys._getframe(1)` if you call the function without arguments. But you could use it on any dictionary now:

```
import string
print(imports(vars(string)))
```

This uses the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) to grab the namespace dictionary of the `string` module, for example. This produces:

```
>>> import string
>>> imports(vars(string))
['re', '_string']
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if the caller passed his `globals()`

Comment: @slezica: perhaps, I'll add that option.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. The argument of sys.getframe is the depth below the call stack the frame object is desired- can you explain why this is '1' in your example? If '0' was used, this returns the frame at the top of the stack - what does this mean? I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: @Mike: each function call is added to the stack; the top is the *current* function, so `sys._getframe(0).f_globals` is the same dictionary as the return value of `globals()`. `1` is the next item on the stack, so the function that called this one. `2` is the one before, etc.